# Error trying to eval a bool?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I only want to show a certain item template if the object's CRMID which is a string that can be null.

If it is null I do not want to show this item template:

```
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                <ItemTemplate>
                <a href="#myModal" id='rm_btn' runat="server" role="button" class="close custom-close"  onclick="showModal('#myModal')" onserverclick="rmbtn"
                    visible='<%# (bool)(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CRMID") == null) ? "true" : "false" %>'>
                    ×</a>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

However I get the following error:

```
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0030: Cannot convert type 'string' to 'bool'

Source Error:


Line 136:                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
Line 137:                    <ItemTemplate>
Line 138:                    <a href="#myModal" id='rm_btn' runat="server" role="button" class="close custom-close"  onclick="showModal('#myModal')" onserverclick="rmbtn"
Line 139:                        visible='<%# (bool)(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CRMID") == null) ? "true" : "false" %>'>
Line 140:                        ×</a>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong...

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried removing the quotes from your values i.e. `? "true" : "false"` -> `? true : false`. There are other ways to tackle this, I can't test them but have compiled them in an answer below.

Comment: Right now, you're sending the true/false back as strings. C# can't directly convert those to boolean values like javascript can. My first thought would be to remove the quotes from them in that `visible` assignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to directly convert `"true"` or `"false"` ie. `string` to bool value. So try `true/ false` instead of string like this.

```
visible='<%# (bool)(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CRMID") == null) ? true : false %>'>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest several attempts:

Remove the quotes

```
// BEFORE
(bool)(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CRMID") == null) ? "true" : "false"

// AFTER
(bool)(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CRMID") == null) ? true : false
```

Or `bool.Parse` it

```
// BEFORE
(bool)(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CRMID") == null) ? "true" : "false"

// AFTER
bool.Parse((DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CRMID") == null) ? "true" : "false")
```

Or straight out remove the check

```
// BEFORE
(bool)(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CRMID") == null) ? "true" : "false"

// AFTER
(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CRMID") == null) /* this is a bool already*/
```